# React Router avoid unmounting

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have 3 routes that use the same component and based on the route display slightly different content. The problem is that on every route change the whole components mounts/unmounts from scratch leading to performance issues. What is the best way to avoid the unmounting but still use the same component and have these 3 routes?

```
<Route path="/Products" exact render={Products} />
<Route path="/Products/shoes" exact component={Products} />
<Route path="/Products/books" exact component={Products} />
```

React Router version 4.

Comment: which version of react-router you are using

Comment: @stack26 version 4

Comment: Can you try `<Route path="/Products/:type?" exact render={Products} />` and see if it mounts/unmounts each time ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can render Route based on route conditional path matching, in which case it wont remount everytime your route changes

```
<Route path="/Products(/shoes|/books)?" exact render={Products} />
```

Answer (score 0):

Shubham's solution is now a little different, here two years later

```
<Route path={["/Products/shoes", "/Products/books", "/Products"]} exact render={Products} />
```

Notice the order.

Answer (score -1):

The routes in parallel will unmount whenever a new route is matched. you need to wrap the component for "/Products/shoes" and "/Products/books" inside Product component. In react-router v4, You need to nest the routes similar to your component. so you need to have product component containing the "/Products" route and other 2 inside the child component.

Frankly speaking I just gave an overview, read through react-router 4 documentation for better understanding.

Comment: That’s not correct. You don’t have to nest. @Shubham is right on replacing `component` prop by `render`.